# Compilation failed while installing plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, preg-replace

I could customize wordpress theme http://www.apptha.com/demo/video-stream in localhost well .
But I am tring to upload in server get the following error.

**Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: missing opening brace after \o at offset 18 in /home/const/public_html/apptha/wp-content/plugins/contus-video-gallery/hdflvvideoshare.php on line 545**

My site is  http://constantin-entertainment.info/apptha/

here Wordpress video gallery plugin is used, the error pointed line is

```
$pageContent = preg_replace_callback( '/\[hdvideo ([^]]*)\o]/i', 'video_shortcodeplace', $pageContent );
```

Please help me..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to escape the backslash,

```
$pageContent = preg_replace_callback( '/\[hdvideo ([^]]*)\\o]/i', 'video_shortcodeplace', $pageContent );
```

Comment: no change, same  Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: missing opening brace after \o at offset 18 in /home/const/public_html/apptha/wp-content/plugins/contus-video-gallery/hdflvvideoshare.php on line 545  what I  do?

Comment: I think it is my server problem, uploaded to another server was successful.. Thank you for  your valuable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Open **\wp-content\plugins\contus-video-gallery\hdflvvideoshare.php** file and find **add_filter('the_content', 'videogallery_pagereplace');** and replace with the following code.

```
add_shortcode('videohome','video_homereplace');
add_shortcode('videomore','video_morereplace');
add_shortcode('hdvideo','video_shortcodereplace');
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$pageContent = preg_replace_callback('/\[hdvideo ([^]]*)\o]/i', 
                                     'video_shortcodeplace', 
                                     $pageContent 
                                    );
```

with

```
$pageContent = preg_replace_callback('/\[hdvideo\s*.*?=(\d+)\]/i', 
                                     'video_shortcodeplace', 
                                     $pageContent
                                    );
```